# How can load some value in the sqlite-database

Tags: android

I have a database now i have to check whether it is empty or not. if empty i have to write the code for insert values otherwise i have to update the values of the fields.
please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 // Open or crare
 myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("MyDatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

 //Check if exists (if not create the table)
 myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTableName (Name1 VARCHAR,  Name2 VARCHAR);");

 //Insert or update your lines
 myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTableName  (Name1 , Name2 ) VALUES ('XXX', 'YYY');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the [Google Notepad tutorials](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) 1,2,3? they have a bunch of database help

Hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to include a .db file in your application package and use that as the starting point for your device-side database. It goes in the assets folder. You'll have to manually copy the values out of that .db into the one on the device in your startup method, but it saves putting a bunch of SQL INSERT calls in code.

The [MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/) Database perspective will assist you with this. You can use it to create a .db from scratch and populate it with your default values. Then, there is a wizard that will set up a content provider and accessor classes for the fields if you need them.

Disclaimer: I'm the product manager for MOTODEV Studio.